# C++ - Maintaining a vector of pointers or addresses

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

So, I'm pretty sure I'm fundamentally misunderstanding pointers/references, but I wanted confirmation.

In my C++ program, I'm trying to maintain vectors of pointers to other objects. The idea being that `faces` would have a vector of pointers to child `edges` and `vertices`, `edges` would have pointers to child `vertices` and parent `faces`, and `vertices` would have references to parent `edges` and `faces`. All of the "master" copies of these objects would be stored in vectors on the `icosahedron` object.

The issue I'm having is that, as soon as I add any new pointer to the vector, the older pointers no longer work. So, while the objects are collecting vectors of pointers to link one another, they only point to the right thing immediately afterwards.

Here's a dumbed down example of what I'm trying, and what's happening:

**main.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class vertex
{
public:
    std::string _id;

    //Constructor
    vertex(std::string id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
};

class icosahedron
{
public:
    std::vector<vertex> _childVertices;
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
    icosahedron ico;

    vertex vert1 = vertex("a");

    ico._childVertices.push_back(vert1);
    std::cout << "\nID of first vector: " << ico._childVertices[0]._id;

    vertex* vert1address = &ico._childVertices[0];
    std::cout << "\nID of vert1 by pointer: " << vert1address->_id;

    vert1address->_id = "b";
    std::cout << "\nID of vert1 by pointer after renaming ID: " << vert1address->_id;

    vertex vert2 = vertex("z");
    ico._childVertices.push_back(vert2);

    std::cout << "\nID of vert1 by pointer after adding vert2 and renaming ID: " << vert1address->_id;

    vert1address->_id = "c";

    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
ID of first vector: a
ID of vert1 by pointer: a
ID of vert1 by pointer after renaming ID: b
ID of vert1 by pointer after adding vert2 and renaming ID:
C:\Users\...\source\repos\StackOverflowTest\StackOverflowTest\x64\Debug\StackOverflowTest.exe (process 7368) exited with code -1073741819.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

So, I'd bet dollars to donuts that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding pointers, and that this idea won't work. Is it fixable? Or is the whole idea totally bad?

Comment: When a vector resizes all existing references and pointers to items in it are invalidated. You'll need to find a different solution, perhaps storing the index of an item. That assumes you only ever add to the back of the vector you're storing indices to. If you add/remove elsewhere then those indices will end up pointing to the wrong item.

Comment: When you start off by saying that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of pointers and references, wouldn't you think it's maybe a good idea to read an article or two about those?

Comment: Thank you, Retired Ninja. I think the indices method will probably work.

Thank you for your reply Emanuel P, but I have read articles on pointers and references, but they were more introductory and glossed over the detail that the pointers get invalidated as soon as new items are added to it.

Comment: Another option is to store the master copies in a std::list instead of std::vector

Comment: Or, store the master copies as `vertex*` pointers in the `vector` (or better, as `shared_ptr<vertex>`), and then store `vertex*` pointers (or `shared_ptr<vertex>`/`weak_ptr<vertex>`) to the master objects in the various classes. IOW, the classes hold pointers to the objects that the vector elements are also pointing at, rather than holding pointers to the vector elements themselves. This way, vector resizes won't invalidate the pointers that the classes are holding.

Comment: Using `shared_ptr` should solve this. The use case however is quite odd. I think you should design your system in a way that just one entity holds the data and manages access to it to the other modules via a common interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @retired-ninja already pointed out: `std::vector` allocates new memory on a resize and copies its contents to that new memory location. Thus any pointers to objects at the old location become invalid in that process. At which occasion a `std::vector` resizes is implementation-defined.

One possibility to solve this specific question is choosing another container type. A `std::deque` would be an obvious choice, IMO. The `std::deque` won't copy or move any contained element when appending. It also uses contiguous memory (chunks), so insertion or deletion of elements **will** move other elements.
Your example class would look like this:

```
class icosahedron
{
public:
    std::deque<vertex> _childVertices;
};
```

As you also ask for an evaluation of the basic idea to use pointers here: Consensus seems to be that there's nothing wrong with using (raw) pointers, **but** you have to be very careful in that. It would be best to encapsulate all pointer handling privately inside the `icosahedron` class and don't allow any raw pointer to leak this confinement. This way you will at least never have bugs in connection with this pointers *outside* this single class.